# How to create an extension to check if an object is one of these type?

Tags: c#, .net, object-type

Normally, when I want to check if an object is one of these types, I use the following code:

```
object a = "ABC";

if (a is string || a is int || a is double)
{

}
```

I want to create an extension method that that shorten this, such as:

```
if (a.IsOneOfTheseType(string, int, double)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions {
    public static bool IsOneOfTypes(this object o, params Type[] types) {
        Contract.Requires(o != null);
        Contract.Requires(types != null);
        return types.Any(type => type == o.GetType());
    }
}
```

I don't have a compiler handy to test / check for stupid mistakes but this should get you pretty close. Note that this satisfies your requirement of "check[ing] if an object is one of [some given] types". If you want to check assignability, replace the lambda expression with

```
type => type.IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType())
```

See [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) for the exact semantics.

To use:

```
object a = "ABC";
bool isAStringOrInt32OrDouble =
    a.IsOneOfTypes(typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(double));
```

or

```
object a = "ABC";
bool isAStringOrInt32OrDouble = 
    a.IsOneOfTypes(new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(double) });
```

Comment: If the poster wants 'Types that can be casted to', use `type.IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType())` in the lambda predicate. +1

Comment: +1 - Note to OP, you need to pass it like this `if (a.IsOneOfTypes(typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(double)))`

Comment: @Simon Belanger: Thanks, I'll life that into the body.

Comment: @keyboardP: Thanks, I'll lift that into the body.